# how to position an element using javascript..?

Tags: javascript

I've hidden my navbar using position. now I want navbar to appear when hamberger icon is clicked.

that's how tried,

```
    var menubtn = document.getElementById("menubtn")
    var rspnsvnavlist = document.getElementById("rspnsvnavlist")
        rspnsvnavlist.style.position = "left(-350px)";        
        menubtn.onclick = function (){
       
        if(rspnsvnavlist.style.position = "left(350px)"){
           rspnsvnavlist.style.position = "left(0)";
        }
        else{
           rspnsvnavlist.style.position = "left(350px)";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `style.position` doesn't take values like `left(-350px)`. It takes values like `absolute`, `relative`, or `static`. Maybe you meant `style.transform = "translateX(350px)"`?

Comment: Why are you using javascript for this? Using CSS classes is the more logical option for this.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question, there seems to be no animation to wanna move the element from a side to another, is there a reason not to just dissapear the element with the `display` property, and change it on click? example

```
 var menubtn = document.getElementById("menubtn")
 var rspnsvnavlist = document.getElementById("rspnsvnavlist")
        
        //hides the element
        rspnsvnavlist.style.display = "none";        
        menubtn.onclick = function (){
       
        //restore the element if it was hidden
        if(rspnsvnavlist.style.display == "none"){
           rspnsvnavlist.style.position = "block";
        }
        else{
           //hide the element if it was showing
           rspnsvnavlist.style.display = "none)";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this would help,

the position property is used for `static`
`relative`
`fixed`
`absolute`
`sticky`

you should try :
`rspnsvnavlist.style.left = "350px";`

The best approach would be using `Element.classList.toggle()`, like [@Roko C. Buljan's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76742932/19459062)

Comment: OP should use Element.classList.toggle(), not manipulate with `Element.style` from JS in the first place.

Comment: you're right @RokoC.Buljan,  the best approach is to use two class and toggle between them, but i was pointing out the mistake  `rspnsvnavlist.style.position = "left(350px)"`

Comment: Not exactly, you don't need to classes. Logic. You need only one. The default state can be store in the element's styles at runtime. You only need one class for the changed state. And that's the only class you need to toggle. See in my example.

Answer (score 1):

- Avoid using `Element.style` from JS. Instead use Element.classList and its methods like `.add()` `.remove()` `.toggle()` to manipulate a class, and style it in CSS accordingly.
- For a good UX/UI, elements should always animate, for the viewer to cognitively perceive motion as a change in the state of the viewing page. Therefore, don't hardcode values like `left: -350px` etc. Simply use `translate` by `-100%` (on a desired axis) to completely move out of view an element. Set the `transition` in order to animate it back into view once the elements gets a class like `"is-active"`
- [Use data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) like `data-toggle="someSelector"` to store the selector of the element you want to toggle such an `is-active` class
- Use `.addEventListener()` instead of bug prone `onclick` handlers. Use event delegation if needed (as in the example below)

Example:

```js
document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const elBtn = evt.target.closest("[data-toggle]");
  if (!elBtn) return;   // Do nothing

  document.querySelector(elBtn.dataset.toggle).classList.toggle("is-active");
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

#rspnsvnavlist {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100dvh;
  background: #0bf;
  
  /* move out of view */
  translate: -100% 0;
  /* allow transition animations */
  transition: translate 0.4s;
}

#rspnsvnavlist.is-active {
  /* move into view */
  translate: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<button data-toggle="#rspnsvnavlist" type="button" aria-label="Open menu">☰ Menu</button>

<div id="rspnsvnavlist">
  <button data-toggle="#rspnsvnavlist" type="button" aria-label="Close menu">✕ Close</button>
  <h2>MENU</h2>
</div>
```

the best part in the above example is in that you can have any number of buttons and different target elements, without the need to code any additional JS code. Just use the class `.is-active` in CSS accordingly for the desired elements - to change their appearance.

Comment: "For a good UX/UI, elements should always animate". I understand where you're coming from with that, but for sliding animations like this it's worth considering if the animation should be disabled for users who have told their browser they prefer reduced motion. Thankfully, that's quite easy in CSS by wrapping the animation or transition rule in an `@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference)` block. [`prefers-reduced-motion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion)

Comment: , this seems like more logical solution.

Comment: @MarkHanna A one-time transition is not a *flashy, loop, marquee, etc* animation that could cause vestibular motion reaction. Indeed, symptoms may vary. Following that argument, websites should not be scrollable to start with, since *scroll = motion*. Disabling that one-time transition will instead cause the menu to appear instantaneously which will cause a significant *flash* which is a greater stimuli. Arguably a fade-In-Out would be preferable. Eventually. Every aspect is to be considered for greater accessibility in mind and `prefers-reduced-motion` is the right tool for the job. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggle( button, label='open' ){
    const id = button?.dataset?.refId;
    const element = document.getElementById( id );
    
    if ( !element ) return null;
    
    if ( element.classList.contains( label ) ) 
        element.classList.remove( label );
    else 
        element.classList.add( label );
}
```

```css
html, body {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: unset;
    margin: unset;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#page-header {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
}

#page-header > div {
    padding: 1rem;
}

#page-header h1 {
    margin: unset;
}

#page-menu-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: -50%;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 30vw;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: #eee;
    transition: 1s ease left;
}

#page-menu-left.open {
    left: 0;
}

#page-menu-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    right: -50%;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 30vw;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: #eee;
    transition: 1s ease right;
}

#page-menu-right.open {
    right: 0;
}

.bars-menu {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


<aside id="page-menu-left">Left Sidebar</aside>
<header id="page-header">
    <div>
        <button class="bars-menu" onclick="toggle(this)" data-ref-id="page-menu-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>  
    <div>
        <button class="bars-menu" onclick="toggle(this)" data-ref-id="page-menu-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
    Document Body
</main>
<footer>
    Document Footer
</footer>
<aside id="page-menu-right">Right Sidebar</aside>
```

Comment: Inline `on*` handler attributes are discouraged in favor of `Element.addEventListener()`

Comment: This answer would be improved by an explanation of how it works.